# How to use Boost headers with Jetbrains Appcode

Tags: c++, boost, appcode

I have the Boost libraries installed on my Macbook via MacPorts and was wondering how to configure AppCode to recognize the headers. 
I tried right clicking on the project `-> Add Frameworks and Libraries -> Other... ->` browse to `/opt/local/include -> Choose` but this doesn't seem to add Boost to the list.

Has anyone successfully gotten Boost to work with AppCode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this via google:

There are three steps involved:

1. Right click on the project and choose `Add Frameworks and Libraries`, followed by `Other`, and browse for all of the dylibs. Since I installed boost via brew, the dylibs were located under `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib/`. Make sure that you select all of them, so that under the new Frameworks folder in your navigation window, a list of all of the boost libraries appear.
   [image: boost libs included]
2. Right click on the project and choose `Project Settings`. Scroll to `Search Paths` and add the path to your boost include directory under `Header Search Paths`. For me it was located under `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/include`. **Make sure that Recursive is unchecked, or you will get compile errors if you are using std!!!**
3. Proceed to add the boost lib dir (that you browsed to in step 1) under `Library Search Paths`. After steps 2 & 3, your search paths may look something like:
   [image: search paths]

Thats it! You are now ready to use boost headers like so:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Just make sure to build in 64-bit mode, since that's what the boost libraries are compiled as (might be different for the macports build).